# During JSON Serialization in .NET, is there a way to specify how "deep" the object graph you wish to go?

Tags: json.net

I have some complex object graphs, when I want to send them down to the client, I'm creating a separate DTO and serializing the objects into that. This is a pain in the ass. Is there anyway to serialize objects and only say, "Go one references deep" so if I have an object:

```
public class Test {
public Project { get; set; }
}

public class Project {
public int Id { get; set; }
public Vendor Vendor { get; set; }
}
```

If I go to serialize Test it won't go to the Vendor, but it'll correctly serialize the Project. I realize I can add an annotation for JsonIgnore, but if I were serializing all Projects, I might want a Vendor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going to have to do some custom extension work: I found a conversation and some samples at http://json.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=24459